# Simple command-line http server for Single Page App

Tags: http, command-line, single-page-application, httpserver

There are various [one-liner HTTP server commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520602/run-a-web-server-from-any-directory), e.g. the best-known is probably `python -m http.server`. I'm looking for a similar command which would run a server that ignores the file path and send all paths to a specific file, e.g. if you visit /foo or /bar, it will serve both from `index.html`.

And ideally relying on as little installation hassle as possible for a typical Linux/MacOS machine. (e.g. python and `http.server` will come out of the box to many users.)

It's the same functionality offered by the htaccess rule `RewriteRule (.*) /index.html`, but without needing to setup Apache. Not sure if any of those one-liner servers support something similar to it, like a command-line argument that would declare the default file for all paths.

Comment: I'm very much not asking for product recommendations and not asking what's the best tool. It's a precisely worded question about how to achieve a real-world programming task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using **php**, there is a [built in development server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) from the command line, which is super useful.

First example, in the current folder, **serving only the file** `index.html`  at `127.0.0.1`, port `8080`:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 index.html
```

Output

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Development Server started at Mon Dec 23 15:37:03 2019
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080
Document root is /home/nvrm
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

On this case, only the file `index.html` will respond at http://127.0.0.1:8080

Any http calls on this port, will be redirected to `index.html`.

---

Second example binding the **whole current folder** to `localhost`, port `5555`:

```
php -S localhost:5555
```

Output:

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Development Server started at Mon Dec 23 09:59:44 2019
Listening on http://localhost:5555
Document root is /home/nvrm
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

This will serve `index.html` at the adresss http://localhost:5555

If a file `index.php` exist, then it will be served first (interpreted as php)

All others files in the (sub)folder(s) are served, example http://localhost:5555/css/style.css will respond as well, if this folder and file exist of course. (Otherwise respond error 404)

---

Third example, to **run from anywhere**, pass in *a path* as third param. Using a local ip is also possible, by doing so, the files are available on the **whole local network**.
Example local ip: *192.168.1.23*.
To retrieve our local ip, we can use `ifconfig`.

```
php -S 192.168.1.23:8080 ~/www
```

This will serve the folder **www** in the home folder on the port 8080: http://192.168.1.23:8080 to everyone on the network.

---

Obviously, **we can run many servers on many different ports in parallel**^
Very useful to dev, but also to quickly share files between virtual machines, devices, phones etc.

---

Alternatively. Listen to all interfaces by using `0.0.0.0` as ip adress. In some cases, this is the sole command that serve well across every devices in the local network.

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:5555
```

And then use the local ip as url:  http://192.168.1.23:5555

---

To be able to close the terminal, but to keep the server running, we can use `nohup`:

```
nohup php -S localhost:8080 &
```

Then to kill it, quickly:

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

---

Last example, using a **hostname**.
To retrieve the machine hostname from the console, the unix command is `hostname`.

```
php -S $(hostname):9999
```

Will bind to something like `http://<session_name>-<machine_name>:9999`

---

It is possible to install only the cli version of php to run this (***~4mo***). It's included in the core.

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

---

For more advanced server usages, yet simple to configure, warmly, I recommend [caddy server](https://caddyserver.com/)

Comment: This is cool, but still doesn't support wildcards unfortunately. i.e. it doesn't use index.html or index.php to serve `/foo`.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You want all queries on the address to be directed  to `index.html`. You can specify the file as 3rd arg: `php -S localhost:8080 index.html` , so even with the call `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css` index.html will respond. Otherwise we can route organise everything using php or node or else, but won't be a one liner. Please clarify with examples, query address and expected results.

Comment: Yes, that's right and works! Can you please update your answer with this to make it more clear and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/svenstaro/miniserve
to serve only `index.html` you just do `miniserve index.html`. It's written in Rust so you don't need any additional dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Except I want it to match on wildcard, i.e. /anything serves a fixed file such as index.html. I'm ideally looking for something that is pre-installed on most Linux/MacOS boxes like the python example.

Comment: miniserve struggle [to serve spa](https://github.com/svenstaro/miniserve/issues/474). I go with microserver.

Answer (score 0):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

server.all('/*', (_, res) => {
  // You would probably not want to hard-code this,
  // but make it a command line argument.
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

const port = 8000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port', port);
});
```

Make the file executable (`chmod +x`) and save it somewhere within your PATH.

Comment: This is very concise, thanks. Ideally hoping to find a one-liner to make the setup instructions even simpler, without having to copypaste.